# javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder.entity returns 500

Tags: java, web-services, exception, jersey

I'm using ResponseBuilder to build my response for my Jersey webservice method

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html#entity%28java.lang.Object%29

It's called this way:

```
try {
    //...
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Response.serverError().entity(ex).build();
    //...
}
```

The webservice method is supposed to return MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, however, it returns a HTML page showing 500: Internal Server Error.

When using Response.ok(variable) for variable of any data type except those inherited from class Exception, everything goes fine with a proper JSON returned.

What happened when I pass 'ex' as parameter to method 'entity'?

Comment: I guess it does not know out-of-the-box how to make a JSON error page. If you require that, you probably have to explicitly create some JSON-serializable description of the exception and use that as the entity. Maybe this can be implemented and plugged-in as a converter.